# How to add an App or a List to a Team Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, app-part

I have a team site with a Home Page like the one on [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-a-sharepoint-team-site-75545757-36c3-46a7-beed-0aaa74f0401e)
(created programmatically with STS#3 template).

I'd like to customize the Home Page adding a SharePoint hosted App I have developed.

But if Edit the page I only see the command "Add a new Web Part":

[image]

How can I add an app to the Home Page?

I dont necessarily use the STS#3 template but I could also use the PROJECTSITE#0  (or maybe STS#0 Team Site classic experience).

**EDIT**

I have added the App to the Web Site both "locally" and globally through Deployment at Site collection scope.

[image]

**NOTE**
I have developed the Add-in (App) using Sharepoint hosted pattern.
In my App I have only the `Default.aspx` page and the code is Javascript inside the `App.js` file.
I haven't used any WebParts and *hopefully* I won't need them.

Comment: did you add the app to site via Add an app ? You first need to install that app in the site collection

Answer (score 0):

Create an add-in part so you could insert the add-in part to a page.

[How to create add-in part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-add-in-parts-to-install-with-your-sharepoint-add-in)

Update:
[image]

Comment: I have read the article, but the problem is that the example is tailored to _provider hosted_ Add-in. That is that in Visual Studio there are two projects (web application project and SharePoint Add-in project). Instead I have a single `SharePoint hosted` project. So for example when at last it says "SharePoint Add-in doesn't have any add-in web, and its remote web application exists only to host the form. So the start page of the add-in should be set to the home page of the host web." I can't understand how to apply this to my case. there aren't any examples around for Sharepoint-hosted?

Comment: Add-in part can be added in both SharePoint hosted/Provider hosted add-in, you can check above screenshot.